# How do I customise the Sentry transport?

Tags: javascript, sentry

Using `"@sentry/browser": "5.30.0"`.

How do I configure Sentry so that I can customise the messages that Sentry sends?

My reading of the documentation is that the [`transport`](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/configuration/options/#transport) property is intended to allow this, but I can't figure out what I'm supposed to pass as the argument.

```
Sentry.init({
  dsn: '...',
  autoSessionTracking: false,
  transport: (options: TransportOptions)=>{
    return new MyFetchTransport(options);
  },
});

class MyFetchTransport extends FetchTransport {
  constructor(options: TransportOptions){
    super(options);
  }

  sendEvent(event: Event): PromiseLike<Response>{
    return super.sendEvent(event);
  }

  sendSession(session: Session): PromiseLike<Response>{
    return super.sendSession(session);
  }
}
```

The above gives a Typescript error of:

```
Type '(options: TransportOptions) => MyFetchTransport' is not assignable to type 'TransportClass<Transport>'.
  Type '(options: TransportOptions) => MyFetchTransport' provides no match for the signature 'new (options: TransportOptions): Transport'.  TS2322
```

What should the init invocation look like if I want to customise how Sentry sends messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an [example](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/blob/70958228db98215fa4a0ef46e3c85ca4566a709f/packages/browser/examples/app.js) in the Sentry docs, the `init()` call should look like:

```
Sentry.init({
  dsn: '...',
  autoSessionTracking: false,
  transport: MyFetchTransport,
});
```